# PhpMailer error : Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed

Tags: php, phpmailer

I search google and this site and can't fix this phpMailer error and that's why I need you help.

I am sending email using following phpMailer code but all time it's showing me error message :

**Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting**

**PhpMailer Code**

```
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();                                     
$mail->Host =  gethostbyname("smtp.gmail.com");  
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                          
$mail->Username = 'hello@gmail.com';        
$mail->Password = 'password';                 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                       
$mail->Port = 465;                               
$mail->isHTML(true);   
$mail->Priority = 1; 

$to = 'to@gmail.com';
$mail->setFrom('support@site.com', 'Sitename');

// Send Email tto user ####################################
$mail->addAddress('some@gmail.com', 'Shibbir Ahmed');
// send email to admin #####################################
$mail->addReplyTo('some@gmail.com', 'Information');

$mail->Subject = 'Test Subject';

$get_templae = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM email_template WHERE t_id = '8' ");
$get_restult =  mysqli_fetch_array($get_templae);
$template =  $get_restult['t_content'];

$mail->Body    = $template;

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

Can you please tell what I am doing wrong in this code ?

I am getting this error :

> 2016-04-21 15:19:51 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111) 2016-04-21 15:19:51 SMTP connect() failed. github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

**Update :**

**Current Error from my server :**

2016-04-21 18:06:01 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111) 2016-04-21 18:06:01   SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting bool(false)

Comment: Try [reading the link](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#enabling-debug-output) And then tell us what **specific** error it tells you about

Comment: Okey I am reading it now.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I am getting this error : 2016-04-21 15:19:51 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111) 2016-04-21 15:19:51 SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting Message could not be sent.Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting

Comment: Oddly enough, it means that your attempt to connect to the mail server was refused. Your access to outbound mail is probably restricted by an ISP firewall, you know, just as the troubleshooting guide and all the other duplicates of this question say.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SMTP error with PHPMailer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185942/smtp-error-with-phpmailer)

Comment: And in future, add any extra information to your question. You can edit it as many times as you like. Nobody can read stuff like that in a comment

Comment: Well, @RiggsFolly I just comment this line : //$mail->isSMTP();  and it's sending email but why it's take 4-5 minutes to send email ?

Comment: You mean the form runs for 4-5 minutes, or it takes that long to see the mail in your mail client?

Comment: I mean when I send email it showing successfully send email and then it's take 4-5 minutes to receive that email.

Comment: Lots of things happen on the round trip from your code to you seeing it again in your mail client. Virus checking, 100000 of other emails going to and from the same mail server, sender validation, etc etc. Will depend on the day and the time and whatever else is going on

Comment: Try Enabling "Allow less secure apps" in your Google account.

Comment: HI Just solved my issue. I have to put my google app password instead of Gmail account password. Now it's sending email successfully from localhost within a seconds but when I upload this same code to my server it's showing me error. Please check my update question.

Answer (score 1):

Try to lower your gmail security, for the SMTP!

Link: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

And add de debuginfo property to see more what is wrong.

$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;

you can change the value to 1 2 3 or 4 to ingress the filtering form debuginfo.

Hope this helps you out ;)

Answer (score 1):

The best ways to debug PHPMailer errors is to uncomment

`$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;`

It will give you a detailed log of the events happening. From authentication all the way to where the request is successful or fails

Answer (score 0):

Step1: Go to Gmail setting and enable IMAP.
Step2: Clear your browser cache and check it.

If issue still persists lower your Gmail security by using "settings" tab.
[Gmail Security alert will be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOqcm.png)